# Expression blend slideshow?

Tags: expression-blend, slideshow

I'm specificaally a photoshop web designer and have a limited knowledge of xaml.
I'm trying to create a slideshow effect with images an text within it, similar to http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Image-slider-control-in-Silverlight-1.1.aspx

Does anyone know how I would create this by just using Expression Blend. I would prefer not to dip into any code! Would be great if there is some sort of behavior for this?

I'm currently using the states and storyboard. The animation works in sketch preview, but I can't get the buttons to work for the behavior gotonextstate.

Any ideas?

Thanks Judi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it for you but don't know how to attache file here so send me your mail to send it to you.

be sure to have the default windows 7 (vista) images fileder to let the sample run fine.

Take care,